# onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance deprecated in AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

`onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` was deprecated in AndroidX when the first version got released back in 2018! As the [AndroidX Activity library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) says in the release notes:

*`onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` has been deprecated. Use a ViewModel for storing objects that need to survive configuration changes.*

I just want a single object to survive configuration changes, this was the purpose of `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`!

For my use case, I want an instance of a Dagger graph to survive configuration changes in an Activity but using AAC ViewModel doesn't feel right to me for that use case. Dagger injects my ViewModels, I don't want to wrap my graph in another ViewModel just for the sake of making it survive configuration changes.

Is there any other way I can make an object survive configuration changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ViewModel` is the most accurate and recommended way to make an object survive configuration changes, you should use it. You could've used `onSaveInstanceState` but that'd force all the objects needing to support `Parcelable`, that's not only reasonable, it's sometimes impossible.

To replace `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance`, you can use the same APIs that support `ViewModel` in a way that handles all the complexity for you.

You can use this implementation of [LongLastingElement API (code here)](https://gist.github.com/manuelvicnt/aab31b72a06dc8f3a7e79d617e6d54bd) that uses `ViewModel` under the hood and removes all the boilerplate code to make an object survive configuration changes.

For your example, to make the Dagger graph survive configuration changes with this API, the code would look like this:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loginComponent: LoginComponent

    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loginComponent = LongLastingElement.getInstance<LoginComponent>(this).getElement {
            (applicationContext as MyDaggerApplication).appComponent.loginComponent().create()
        }

        loginComponent.inject(this)
    }
}
```

LongLastingElement has a static method called `getInstance` where you specify the type of the object that needs to be stored and you pass a lifecycle owner in. Then, the `getElement` method is called, it receives a lambda as a parameter that needs to create an instance of the object you want to store.

Since the Lifecycle owner is used to obtain the `LongLastingElement` instance, the lambda that `getElement` takes as a parameter will be only called once. It'll create an instance of the object the very first time is called and the same instance will be reused after configuration changes and subsequent calls to `getElement`. This works for any lifecycle owner such as Activities and Fragments.